# Calculation of minimum no. of colors

Tags: graph-theory

Minimum no. of colors required to colour the vertices of a cycle with n nodes in such a way that no two adjacent nodes have same colour

Comment: You could at least write a complete sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$2+\lceil n/2\rceil-\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ if $n>1$.